# Sorting out the dates in chronological order

Tags: java, android

Friends I am having a String that contains date-record

```
String date=10-Oct-2012 @12-Oct-2012 @$12-Oct-2012 @12-Oct-2012 @$12-Sept-2012 13:50@12-Oct-2012 13:50@$12-Feb-2012 13:50@12-Oct-2012 13:50@$

List<Date> myList=new ArrayList<Date>() ;
```

I need to compare the dates `10-Oct-2012,12-OCt-2012,12-Sept-2012,12-Feb-2012` ie every odd date such that I can arrange them in a chronological order.I am confused on this implementation, please provide me with guidance/hint to solve the problem.

In this case the solution after chronological order would be `12-Feb-2012 @12-Oct-2012 @12-Sept-2012  @12-Oct-2012  @$10-Oct-2012 @12-Oct-2012 @$12-Oct-2012 @12-Oct-2012`

Friends,to solve the problem I have created a Hashmap where I am planning to save the first date as key and the entire String as value.

```
String[] tokens=date.split("\\$");
    demo[0]=demo[0].replaceAll("-", ".");
if(tokens.length>0)
        {
            for(int iTmp=tokens.length-1;iTmp>=0;iTmp--)
            {
                String []demo = tokens[iTmp].split("\\@");
                    demo[0] = demo[0].replace("Jan", "1")
                    .replace("Feb", "2").replace("March","3").replace("April","4").replace("May","5").replace("Jun","6").replace("July","7").replace("Aug","8")
                    .replace("Sept","9").replace("Oct","10").replace("Nov","11").replace("Dec","12");
                    demo[0]=demo[0]+" 00:05:00";
                    Date date1 = null;
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");


                    try {
                        date1 = (Date)formatter.parse(demo[0]);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    myList.add(date1);
                    System.out.println("ADDED DATE IS"+date1);
                    //System.out.println("KEY VALUE PAIRS  "+key+"  "+tokens[iTmp]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("READING LISTs");
            for(int iTmp=0;iTmp<myList.size();iTmp++)
            {

                System.out.println(myList.get(iTmp));
            }
            Collections.sort(myList);
            System.out.println("After Sorting");
            for(int iTmp=0;iTmp<myList.size();iTmp++)
            {

                System.out.println(myList.get(iTmp));
                System.out.println();
            }
```

Comment: don't store/handle/work on dates as strings, to begin with.

Comment: Please find the updated question

Comment: ok. and what is the error now (also, i don't understand the list you wrote as what should be the actual result)

Comment: i don't see any hashmap, either

Comment: @njzk2 I have sorted the first date(half task is done.)Now, depending on that values,I need to updated the entire String

Comment: i don't understand, but i think you are not parsing the time

Comment: so, what "half the task" means, what is this entire string you are mentionning, and on what values does that depends ?

Comment: I am able to sort the FIrst date, just need to modify the entire String.
 Sun Feb 12 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012
 Wed Sep 12 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012
 Wed Oct 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012
 Fri Oct 12 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012

Comment: that looks sorted to me. what string do you need to modify ?

Comment: I need to modify the date String

Comment: why? how? from what value to what value? do you mean the representation? i don't see any UI in your code, so i don't know where you need to actually have a representation to you dates

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17933/discussion-between-onkar-and-njzk2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds pretty simple to me:

- Parse each value into a more suitable type (`Calendar`, `Date`, Joda Time's [`LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sf.net))
- Sort in natural order

(Using Joda Time is the preferred option here IMO, as neither `Calendar` nor `Date` really represent "just a date"; you'd have to put all values into the same time zone etc.)

I would definitely *not* recommend trying to compare them *as strings*. As usual, convert your data into the most appropriate type for the information it's trying to represent as early as possible - and convert it into serializing representations (e.g. for storage, propagation to a web service etc) as late as possible.

Comment: everything @JonSkeet said plus a little hint, you can use Collections.sort() to sort the values for you.

Comment: Hey mate I am looking for a calender app where user is permitted to add a combination of entries. I am saving those entries(txt file) and reading them for history. Please help me in improving my approach

Comment: @onkar: Ideally, save your data in a more machine-friendly fashion, e.g. as ISO-8601 values. 12-Feb-2012 is culture-sensitive; 2012-02-12 is standardized (assuming a Gregorian calendar, admittedly...) As ever with software engineering, you need to break your task up: 1) read data from the text file; 2) parse the data into more useful values; 3) manipulate the data, e.g. sorting

Comment: Ok mate. natural order means which sorting shall I work on ? Thanks a ton for your valuable guidance

Comment: Hey mate I have added my approach, please check it.

Comment: @onkar: Could you please stop with the "mate"? And no, there's no need to create a `HashMap`. Just create a list and call Collections.sort...

Comment: Oh.. Sorry. I have successfully sorted the first entry(Using collection) ? How do I override the old history ?

Comment: @onkar: Your updated question seems to be confused - you've posted incomplete code (no declaration of `myList`) which doesn't match the text (it's presumably a list, not a map now), you're ignoring parse failures (really bad idea), and you haven't said what the result is. It's not clear what you expect anyone to be able to do with your question in its current state.

Comment: @onkar: No, you haven't. Everything I complained about in the previous edit is still the case.

Comment: I am able to sort the FIrst date, just need to modify the entire String. Sun Feb 12 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012 Wed Sep 12 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012 Wed Oct 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012 Fri Oct 12 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012 –

Comment: @onkar: Sorry, you're really not making much sense to me. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and take the time to edit your question into a *good* question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17931/discussion-between-onkar-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 0):

Split the string and then

You can use gregorian calender (built in)

or you can use the yoda-time library

i can't say more about the sorting though

Comment: I think it not `yoda-time` it is actually Joda Time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for Android (there is an Android tag on your question), then you should know about the [Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) structures and methods in the Android SDK.

If possible, try to use a string representation of your date/time stamp that itself can be sorted naturally, like the [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) format (which Android supports with built-in methods).  This will let you work more easily with string timestamps, and also give you a simple way to convert to a canonical or integer-type format if desired.